How to suppress Sign[...] in output
I get the following expression in an output:
Sign[a^2 - 2]

How to suppress or avoid it from the input? I tried 'Assumptions', ComplexExapnd, etc. But it does not work.

Sign[a^2 - 2] /. Sign -> Identity?

If you want to suppress it in a multiplicative expression like: ex Sign[a^2 - 2] /. Sign[a^2 - 2]->1. This will return: ex

@DanielHuber: What about the argument?

Do you want to suppress  Sign[a^2 - 2] or  replace Sign[a^2 - 2] by a^2 - 2 ?

Assumptions work for me: Simplify[Sign[a^2 - 2], Assumptions -> a > 2].  But not all assumptions are valid.  The value Sign[] is -1, 0, or 1.  Which is the desired value? The problem is not clear as stated.  DeleteCases[expr, _Sign, Infinity] will suppress all instances of Sign[..] in expr, if you just want to censor them out.

Is a a complex number? Please clarify.

It's a shame that the OP abandoned this question without clarifying all that needed explanation.

@Goofy: No 'a' is real.

There is no point in suppressing it without changing the value of the expression.
You can transform it into a Piecewise expression with PiecewiseExpand. For example:
PiecewiseExpand[Sign[a^2 - 2],a∈Reals]



Another way, for a different use-case than the one in @rhermans's answer:
ComplexExpand[Sign[a^2 - 2], a, TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}]
(* Cos[Arg[-2 + a^2]] + I Sin[Arg[-2 + a^2]] *)

% // FullSimplify
(*  E^(I Arg[-2 + a^2])  *)

There are, of course, more variations:
TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}  (* < long > *)
TargetFunctions -> Conjugate (* (-2+a^2)/Sqrt[(-2+a^2)(-2+Conjugate[a]^2)] *)
TargetFunctions -> {Abs}     (* (-2 + a^2)/Abs[-2 + a^2] *)
< etc. >

